# Show that a function of $\lambda$ is monotone

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

In my research I ran into the following problem

> Show that $$f(\lambda)=E\left[\exp\left(\frac{-X+\lambda Y}{\lambda+1}\right)\right]$$ is monotone in $\lambda$. Where $X,Y$ are possibly unbounded but otherwise nice, fixed, random variables.

Or at least, I hope this is true. I took the derivative to get

$$f'(\lambda)=E\left[\exp\left(\frac{-X+\lambda Y}{\lambda+1}\right)\frac{X+Y}{(\lambda+1)^2}\right]$$

This looks like depending on the sign of $E[X+Y]$, we either have $f'(\lambda)\geq 0$ or $f'(\lambda)\leq 0$ for all $\lambda$. I've tried using various inequalities, but I can't quite show this. I would either like a proof or a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of the negative sign in front of $X$ is curious...  If $X$ is not e.g. constrained to be non-negative, then the negative sign isn't really adding anything to the problem.

Anyway, here is a counter-example:

- $-X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. Bernoulli with $P(Y=0) = P(Y=1) = P(-X=0) = P(-X=1) = 1/2$.
- $f(0) = E[exp(-X)] = {1 + e \over 2}$
- $f(\infty) = E[exp(Y)] = {1 + e \over 2}$
- $f(1) = E[exp( {-X + Y \over 2})] = {1 + 2\sqrt{e} + e \over 4} \neq {1 + e \over 2}$

Comment: It was something that came up in research. There was a negative sign there. But yes. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.  In fact I was surprised by my own counter-example.  Your conjecture sounds quite plausible...  I wonder if there are some reasonably general conditions under which it is true (which may include your particular research scenario).  E.g. is it true when $X,Y$ are both non-negative?

Comment: @user658409 you should still make your questions as simple as possible for MSE

Comment: @mathworker21 - While I agree with you, the OP's extra negative sign actually brought up an interesting variant: Is the conjecture true if both $X,Y$ are non-negative?  IMHO it is now much more plausible.  My counter-example doesn't apply any more, and in a sense, there is now "true separation" when you try to interpolate between $Y$ and $-X$.

Comment: @mathworker21 - If $X,Y$ are positive, the conjecture must be true, since on a per-sample-point $\omega \in \Omega$ basis, the interpolated value is monotonically-increasing in $\lambda$.  So the modified conjecture is not that interesting after all.  Oh well.  :)